# I use Future.delayed() to switch to a new screen after a few seconds but it jumps to that page over and over again

Tags: android, flutter, future

Weird issue but I cant seem to fix this. I have used `Future.delayed()` to switch to another screen like this:

```
 TextButton(
    label: Text('Submit'),
    onPressed: () {
      showDialog(context: context,
        builder: (context) {
         Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 6), () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context,'/',);
           });
         }
       )
```

Which also shows an AlertDialog with Text that I did not include now but more importantly takes the user back to the homepage after 6 seconds. This happens at 'the end' of the app. However when I start using the app again from there it jumps back to the homepage again after 6 seconds. When I press nothing, nothing happens

Shouldnt the `Future.delayed()` be only called when I press the button it was used in? There is only one button at the homepage - a completely different one - that does something completely else when pressed. So why does it jump back and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

The Navigator saves its routes in a stack. So, when you push to it, it adds the route you're pushing on the top of the stack! this might explain the weird behaviour you're are facing.

If you want to go back to the home screen, you should use `Navigator.pop()`. However, you are using a `showDialog()` function. So the first `pop()` will target the dialog itself and then the second `pop()` will move to the previous screen.

If you just want to send user **back** to the home screen and dismissing all other routes you could use this:

```dart
void _goHome() {
  navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()),
    ModalRoute.withName('/'),
  );
}
```